# pass Class<T> interface to retrofit for differnet webservice

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, retrofit

I have different webservice interface for retrofit library

I want pass class to create method in retrofit

```
class ApiProvider {

companion object {

    fun <T> apiProvider(t: T): T{
        var apiService = ApiClient.provideRetrofit()?.create(t!!::class.java)
        return apiService!!
    }

}
```

but i cant do it

I have this error text:
**API declarations must be interfaces.**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you my way, declare this interface

```
interface BaseApiService
```

and then inheritance your APIs from this interface for example:

```
interface HomePageApiService:BaseApiService {}
```

and write your API provider function like this

```
fun apiProvider(apiService:BaseApiService): BaseApiService{
    return ApiClient.provideRetrofit()?.create(apiService::class.java)
}
```